# www. of domain name not found (on PC)

Tags: domains

I have a domain name setup with LCN but I'm having a problem with the www. part of it on a PC.

On a mac if you type in [www.teamworksdesign.com](http://www.teamworksdesign.com) if we direct you to our holding page. However, if you type this in on a PC it goes to a page not found. If you remove the www. it works though.

This is what we have setup in our account:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on?

UPDATE:
This is what I have in my web server:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the pc is caching a previous DNS miss.

[`http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html`](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html)

Comment: It's doing the same on several different computers so don't think it's that.

Comment: Er wait... a CNAME should alias to a name, not an IP. Get rid of it, it's conflicting with the A record.

Comment: Ok CNAME's gone from LCN (the top image in my question), still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, *now* it's probably a caching issue. :)

Comment: Works ok for me in IE8 on my XP test machine, both with and without the www.

Comment: I've just tried the site on a PC that no one has been on the site before and tried the address with www. and it just redirects me to a search engine. Caching would only be a problem if someone had been on the site on that computer. This is what I can't work out.

Comment: @Rob: the local PC is not the only one caching. It might very well be that your local network and/or ISP has the name in its cache too.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server set up to answer both of the domain names? Some browsers tries adding/removing the www-part if it's not working.

Read up on [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) for apache (if that's what you are using)

Comment: I've updated my question with another image.

Comment: That picture looks more like another DNS config than a web server config?

Comment: It's the hosting control panel.